# if same username for same client id exist in db then it should say username already exist in YII

Tags: yii

```
public function rules()
{
    array('uname', 'unique'),

}
```

I want to check if username exist with same client id then only it should say same username exist now it is showing username exist by check all the client id.
Please help me out.I am new to YII..Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use some extension to achieve this. Take a look at

http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/unique-multiple-columns-validate/

it validates attribute using values of two or more attributes